# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.- Help:(

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Create_Student
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim myqry As String = Nothing
    Dim mycmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim mydr As OleDbDataReader
    Private Sub btn_createAccount_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_createAccount.Click

        'Connecting to the databae
        Try
            With conn
                If .State = ConnectionState.Open Then .Close()
                .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb"
                .Open()

            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try


        Dim student_Name As String
        Dim student_Username As String
        Dim student_Password As String
        Dim student_Group As String

        student_Name = txt_firstname.Text & " " & txt_surname.Text
        student_Username = LCase(txt_Username.Text)
        student_Password = txt_password.Text
        student_Group = cbo_tutorGroup.SelectedItem


        'This chunk of code is reading the username column in the student account table in my database and doing a read to see if the inputted username is already existent in the table.


        myqry = "SELECT studentUser FROM TblStudents"
        mycmd = New OleDbCommand(myqry, conn)
        mydr = mycmd.ExecuteReader
        While mydr.Read
            Dim user As String = mydr("studentUser").ToString
            If user = student_Username Then
                MsgBox("Username already exists, please choose another")

            Else

                Dim sqlQry As String
                sqlQry = "INSERT INTO TblStudents(studentName, tutorGroup, studentUser, studentPass) VALUES('" & student_Name & "','" & student_Group & "','" & student_Username & "','" & student_Password & "')"
                With mycmd
                    .CommandText = myqry
                    .Connection = conn
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With

                MsgBox("Your account has successfully been created")

                Me.Hide()
                Login_Student.Show()
            End If
        End While
```

Comment: Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask]

Comment: The exception message is very clear.  You are attempting to use a Command object on another query when it is still in use.

Answer (score 0):

```
  mycmd = New OleDbCommand(myqry, conn)
```

This is where you declare your cmycmd command.
You then open the reader with

```
 mydr.Read
```

This reader remains open during your if statement, and in your if statement you are opening another reader, using the same "mycmd" . This cannot happen as you already have this reader open, either declare a whole new cmd and open that and close it after your write, or try the following:

```
Dim test as Boolean = False
While mydr.Read
    Dim user As String = mydr("studentUser").ToString
    If user = student_Username Then
        MsgBox("Username already exists, please choose another")

    Else
        test = True

    End If

End While
'Close connection and reopen conn
Try
    With conn
        If .State = ConnectionState.Open Then .Close()
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb"
        .Open()
    End With

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try


If test = True then

    Dim sqlQry As String
        sqlQry = "your query here"
        With mycmd
            .CommandText = myqry
            .Connection = conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With

        'Close currently open connection again
        conn.Close()

        MsgBox("Your account has successfully been created")

        Me.Hide()
        Login_Student.Show()
```

It's best to move your whole connection into a module and run your connections there, as well as commonly used database reads/writes. This is reduces overall code and allows you to reuse common code.